# Stepping with lambda

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket

```
(define (f y) (lambda (y) (lambda (y) (+ y 5))))
```

(((f 3) 4) 5)`

I would like to take the steps of this.

Comment: Nice assignment stepper question! :)

Comment: Please don't completely change your question. That invalidates the answers that people have taken time to write. If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate:

```
(((f 3) 4) 5)
```

Where f =

```
(define (f y) (lambda (y) (lambda (y) (+ y 5))))
```

---

Start with `(f 3)`

```
(f 3) ;; yields ...

(lambda (y)
  (lambda (y)
    (+ y 5)))
```

Next, according to `((f 3) 4)` we apply the result of `(f 3)` to `4`

```
((lambda (y)
   (lambda (y)
     (+ y 5))) 4) ;; yields

((lambda (y)
       (lambda (y)
         (+ y 5))) 4)
```

Next, according to `(((f 3) 4) 5)`, we apply the result of `((f 3) 4)` to `5`

```
((lambda (y)
   (+ y 5)) 5) ;; yields ...

((lambda (y)
   (+ y 5 5)) 5)
```

So the final answer is `(+ 5 5)`, which is `10`

Comment: @AnamayaGarodia there are no substitutions to make. `(f 3)` just returns `(lambda (y) (lambda (y) (+ y 5)))`

Comment: Functions defined with lambda instantly returns the result expression from the function with the arguments substituted in!